Stripe yearly payment but monthly reward roll out
I am trying to make it so the user can pay once (the yearly bill) and get a discount for doing so, but there should be a number of credits (currency) awarded to them monthly. This can be done with a CRON I guess, but I have the following questions:

Is there a way to implement this monthly reward roll out through stripe? Possibly get stripe.subscription_updated events rolled out monthly so I can handle the logic?
Can I use the same subscription product from stripe, but make it be billed once yearly for the whole amount instead of it being a monthly payment?


Stripe Billing should primarily be used for payments, rather than your app business logic. However, it is possible to achieve this with a few workarounds:

Create one Subscription with annual Price, and one Subscription with monthly Price and 100% discount, on the same Customer. Use the first one to collect payments and the second to receive renewal Events.
Create a monthly Subscription with a 100% discount and create one-off Invoices once a year.

But overall I would recommend handling credit awards on your own with cron, and letting Stripe take care of the payments with a single annual Subscription.
